# Weak* convergence of a sequence of gradients

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

We know that if there exists $C$ such that $||\Phi_\epsilon||_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{d})}\leq C$ and $||\nabla \Phi_\epsilon||_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{d})}\leq C$, then there exists two subsequences and two functions $\Phi_1, \ \Phi_2 \in L^{\infty}$ such that $\Phi_{\epsilon_j} \rightharpoonup \Phi_1$ weakly* in $L^{\infty}$ and $\nabla \Phi_{\epsilon_k} \rightharpoonup \Phi_2$ weakly* in $L^{\infty}$ by Banach-Alaouglu theorem. Is it true that $\Phi_2=\nabla \Phi_1$?

Comment: Why not? Use the definition of weak derivative and pass to the limit there.

Comment: I tried but I am not sure about my computations. Can you show me how you would prove it?

Comment: You could include your try in the question.

Comment: I started by writing the definition of weak* convergence in $L^{\infty} but only with test function, so that I can integrate by parts and put the gradient to the test function. Then I use the density of test functions in L^1.

Comment: To be honest I am not sure about this. What you can certainly do is to just take a sub-subsequence $\nabla \Phi_{\varepsilon_{j_r}}$ converges. This limit is clearly $\nabla \Phi_1$. Remember, it still holds that $\lVert \nabla \Phi_{\varepsilon_j} \rVert \leq C$.

Comment: Of course, you need that the subsequences are the same: first choose one such that $\Phi_{\epsilon_n}$ converges, then select a subsequence of this on with converging gradients.

Answer (score 0):

So it is not true, but to circumnavigate this you can follow the hint that @daw and I gave in the comments. A counterexample would be
$$
\Phi_n(x) = (-1)^n\sin(x)
$$
for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $d = 1$.

The subsequence $\Phi_{2n}$ converges to $\sin$, whereas the subsequence $\Phi_{2n+1}'$ converges to $-\cos$.

Obviously $\sin' \neq -\cos$.